# Can't follow HTML5 download link from inside jQuery Deferred handler

Tags: jquery, html, download, jquery-deferred

#### What I am trying to do

I am developing a web application. (Super exciting, I know!) Users should be offered a file for download when clicking on a specific button. The content of this file is generated on-the-fly in an asynchronous operation.

#### How I am doing it currently

The HTML of my page contains markup for the "Download" button that looks like this (note that the absence of an `href` attribute is intentional):

```
<a id="download-button" download="data.txt">Download</a>
```

According to [this resource](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download), in HTML5 the `download` attribute

> signifies that the resource it points to should be downloaded by the browser rather than navigating to it.

The "Download" button has a jQuery click handler associated with it that looks like this:

```
$('#download-button').on('click', function(e) {
  var button = $(e.currentTarget);
  if (!button.attr('href')) {
    foo.frob().then(function(content) {
      var blob = new Blob(content, { type : 'text/plain' });
      var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
      button.attr('href', url);
      button.click();
    });
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});
```

... where `foo` is a `Backbone.Collection` object and `frob` is a method that returns a jQuery promise for the downloadable content. The value of the missing `href` attribute of the "Download" button is created when button is clicked for the first time, and the attribute is then added to the corresponding HTML element. When clicking the button a second time, I am instructing the browser to simply *follow the link* (which, because of the presence of the `download` attribute, should result in the browser prompting the user about whether or not they would like to download the generated content).

#### The Problem

Currently, the browser is refusing to follow the link. *Triggering* the `click` event on the button works, because I can successfully `alert` or `console.log` a message before `return true` in the `else` portion of the code.

#### Additional observations

The problem goes away if I remove the asynchronous computation and instead populate the `Blob` with some arbitrary data.

Also, if I replace

```
button.attr('href', url);
button.click();
```

with

```
window.location = url;
```

the browser *will* follow the link, but instead of offering to download the file it will display the contents on a new page.

Comment: Try `button[0].click()`.

Comment: @JasonP That seems to do it, thanks. But why? Do you want to post your comment as an answer and elaborate a little? :)

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery `.click()` function only triggers click handlers. The native `click()` method causes the link to be followed:

```
button[0].click()
```

Comment: I see, but why would `button.click()` work if I remove the asynchronous computation?

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. But generally if you want to follow a link, you have to use the native `click()` method on the native element object.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway. Maybe someone else will come along in the next few days who can shed more light on this; if not I'll accept your answer and ask a separate question about it. +1 right now for helping me get rid of the problem.

Comment: With the asynchronous computation removed, I expect that `button.click()` still doesn't work however by not returning `false`, the natural hyperlink/download action (now with href in place) is allowed to fire. With the asynchronous computation in place, I can only think that the browser must perform a check to ensure that an infinite recursion of the click handler does not occur. Just in case some browsers don't perform this check (or just for completeness), you should return `false` at the bottom of the `if (!button.attr('href')) {...}` block.